# How do you load from db into richtextctrl?

Tags: wxpython

the following loads contents of richtextctrl (text) into db, when I query db it looks correct.

```
        out = BytesIO()
        handler = wx.richtext.RichTextXMLHandler()
        rt_buffer = self.text.GetBuffer()
        handler.SaveFile(rt_buffer, out)
        self.xml_content = out.getvalue()
        cx.execute("insert into notes (key, data) values (?, ?)", (key, self.xml_content))
        self.conn.commit()
```

question how do I get it back from db and load  into richtextctrl ?

Comment: Dennis, please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Not many people have the time or inclination to write test code from scratch, just to provide an answer, especially involving Gui's

Answer (score 0):

You can work with open file as
You can query for data from db save it in a cursor and then depending on content you can write it into file

```
file = open('file_name.txt', "w")
file.write("content")
```

You can then try looping for multiple line data.